# LAST Cell with valid data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with Date as a index and 2 columns called `dogs` and `cats`. For example:

```
date(index)  cat   dog
2020-06-30   NaN    2
2020-07-01   2      NaN
2020-07-02   NaN    8
2020-07-03   3      NaN
2020-07-04   NaN    6
```

I can't use the tail function. What I want to return is for cats and dogs the last dates where each data column has a valid value.

Comment: Any reason why these need to remain in the same dataframe?  Are you using pandas?

Comment: yes using pandas... its just in the dataframe as NaN

I tried using isnotnull() and i figuring out the best way to get the index.. i can use a crude loop.... but i am tinking there is a better way in pandas

Comment: I'd split it into 2 dataframes if I were you. Unless there are other parts to the dataframe you don't show here

Comment: df.dropna(subset=['cats']).tail(1)


this gives me what i need

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df.iloc[::-1].idxmax()
```

Comment: this gives me what i want... 

how do i return the index value?

    df.dropna(subset=['cats']).tail(1)